# How to get nice Print of References Title in ToC with Beamer?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, table-of-contents

I would like to get a nice print of the References title in the Table of Contents (ToC) with:

- No page number near after the references title in ToC;
- Same format as for a section title in ToC (same color and item - "bullet", "rectangle", etc. - if presents);
- Same vertical spaces between section titles in ToC (above and below the title print);
- Clickable hyperlink working;

Here a MWE with `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default]` (but it would be perfect if the solution automaticly adapt if this `default` option is changed to something else...):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{a section}
    \section{another section}
        \subsection{a subsection}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}       
        \cite{PukSte13}
    \end{frame}

    
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bib}
    \label{bibliography}      
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With `testbib.bib` file:

```
@book{PukSte13,
  title = {Control of Fuel Cell Power Systems: Principles, Modeling, Analysis and Feedback Design},
  author = {Pukrushpan, Jay T. and Stefanopoulou, Anna G. and Peng, Huei},
  date = {2013-03-09},
  edition = {2004e édition},
  publisher = {{Springer}}
}
```

So, instead of this:

[image]

---

I would like something like this:

[image]

---

And/or this with`\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball]`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `biblatex`'s `\printbibliography` uses `\section*` to typeset its heading. Apparently your modification is not compatible with the starred (unnumbered) `\section` command (and for the balls you'd need numbered sections anyway). You need to make the commands use `\section` instead.

Use

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
```

instead of `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`.

Then

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{a section}
    \section{another section}
        \subsection{a subsection}

    \begin{frame}
        \cite{sigfridsson}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bib}
    \label{bibliography}      
    \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

works as desired

[image: nicely aligned ToC]

Comment: It's just perfect ! Thanks a lot ! I updated this question (only related to `biblatex` now) and split the question by asking another one related to `glossaries` only (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/632630/262081)). Please tell me if that wasn't a good thing to do. Thanks again !

Comment: @SylvainRigal Generally it is not recommended to significantly edit a question after it has been answered. But I guess I kind of asked for it (even though I specifically said *for future reference*)... I copied the relevant part to the other answer.