# How to get nice Print of Glossary Title in ToC with Beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to get a nice print of the Glossary title in the Table of Contents (ToC) with:

- No page number near after the glossary title in ToC;
- Same format as for a section title in ToC (same color and item - "bullet", "rectangle", etc. - if presents);
- Same vertical spaces between section titles in ToC (above and below the title print);
- Clickable hyperlink working;

Here a MWE with `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default]` (but it would be perfect if the solution automaticly adapt if this `default` option is changed to something else...):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={1}}   
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{
    name={Compressor},
    text={compressor},
    sort={compressor},
    description={Air Compressor},
    symbol={cp},
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={Compressor Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={compressor motor},
    description={Motor of the \Gls{compressor}},
    symbol={cm},
    parent=subsytem
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{a section}
    \section{another section}
        \subsection{a subsection}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}       
        \gls{compressor_motor};
        \gls{compressor}        
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Glossary} 
    \label{Glossary}      
    \printnoidxglossary
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

So, instead of this:

[image]

---

I would like something like this:

[image]

---

And/or this with`\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball]`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `glossaries`/`glossaries-extras`'s `\printnoidxglossary` and friends use `\section*` to typeset their heading. Apparently your modification is not compatible with the starred (unnumbered) `\section` command (and for the balls you'd need numbered sections anyway). You need to make the commands use `\section` instead.

This can be done by passing the option `numberedsection` to `glossaries`/`glossaries-extra`.

Then

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=tree,numberedsection]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={4}}   
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{
    name={Compressor},
    text={compressor},
    sort={compressor},
    description={Air Compressor},
    symbol={cp},
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={Compressor Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={compressor motor},
    description={Motor of the \Gls{compressor}},
    symbol={cm},
    parent=subsytem
}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{a section}
    \section{another section}
        \subsection{a subsection}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}       
        \gls{compressor_motor};
        \gls{compressor}        
        \bigskip    
        
        \cite{sigfridsson}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Glossary} 
    \label{Glossary}      
    \printnoidxglossary
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bib}
    \label{bibliography}      
    \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

works as desired

[image: nicely aligned ToC]